# this.props.history is not redirecting to homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to redirect the user back to the index page, when a user clicks `handleSubmit`. However the data gets sent to the backend, but stays on the page with the user information still keyed in.

It does not render an error.

Here is the demo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h9ekc4

**Navbar**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import SignIn from './SignIn';
const Navbar = () => {
    return(

    <Router>
        <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/SignUp">Sign Up </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link  className="nav-link" to="/SignIn">Sign In </Link>
                </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <Route path="/SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/SignIn" component={SignIn} />

    </div>
    </Router>
    );

}

export default Navbar;
```

**SignUp.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {signUp ,onEmailSignUpChangeAction,onPasswordSignUpChangeAction} from '../actions/';
class SignUp extends Component {
    state = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }

    // onChange = (e) =>{
    //   this.setState({
    //       [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    //   })
    // }
    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const register = this.props.signUp();
        // this.props.history not working
        (register === true) && this.props.history.push('/');
        console.log(this.state);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                        <div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="email"
                                    onChange={this.props.onEmailSignUpChangeAction}
                                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                    value={this.props.emailSignUp}
                                    placeholder="Enter email"/>
                                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="password"
                                    value={this.props.passwordSignUp}
                                    onChange={this.props.onPasswordSignUpChangeAction}
                                    placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.auth.user,
    emailSignUp:state.signUpAuth.emailSignUp,
    passwordSignUp:state.signUpAuth.passwordSignUp

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    signUp: () => dispatch(signUp()),
    onEmailSignUpChangeAction: (event) => dispatch(onEmailSignUpChangeAction(event.target.value)),
    onPasswordSignUpChangeAction: (event) => dispatch(onPasswordSignUpChangeAction(event.target.value)),
}); 


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your action `signUp()` is not returning anything.
`register = this.props.signUp()` is always `undefined` and hence the below line never executes.

```
(register === true) && this.props.history.push('/');
```

Try returning `true/false` based on your logic and then try running your code again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your **dispatch** call `this.props.signUp()` is returning `undefined`, hence `this.props.history.push('/')` is not executing.

just tried to add a `console.log`

```
handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const register = this.props.signUp();
    console.log(register);
    (register === true) && this.props.history.push('/');
    console.log(this.state);

}
```

[image]

**register** dispatch should be returning **boolean**.

Comment: I still get a unefined error, however i see it show up on the firebase backend.